# How to push data from database and see vote count after each data?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

What I'm trying to do is to allow students answer questions and see each vote after each question and then the teacher can push the next question. The votes will then be entered into the database which I can use to produce a chart. I currently have the student answering questions but I'm having problem on stopping the next question from coming so the poll vote can show and how to show the vote before the next question comes.
This gets the questions from the database:

```
function getQuestion(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (hr.readyState==4 && hr.status==200){
        var response = hr.responseText.split("|");
        if(response[0] == "finished"){
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response[1];
        }
        var nums = hr.responseText.split(",");
        document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = nums[0];
        document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML = nums[1];
        document.getElementById('answers').innerHTML += nums[2];
    }
}
hr.open("GET", "questions.php?question=" + <?php echo $question; ?>, true);
  hr.send();
function post_answer(){
var p = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var id = document.getElementById('qid').value;
        var url = "userAnswers.php";
        var vars = "qid="+id+"&radio="+x();
        p.open("POST", url, true);
        p.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        p.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(p.readyState == 4 && p.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = '';
        alert("Your answer was submitted"+ p.responseText);
        var url = 'quiz.php?question=<?php echo $next; ?>';
        window.location = url;
}
}

p.send(vars);
document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "processing...";

}
```

On a different php file:

```
    require_once 'core/init.php';
$arrCount = "";
if(isset($_GET['question'])){
    $question = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', "", $_GET['question']);
    $output = "";
    $answers = "";
    $q = "";
       $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'alsp');
    $sql = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT id FROM questions");
    $numQuestions = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
    if(!isset($_SESSION['answer_array']) || $_SESSION['answer_array'] < 1){
        $currQuestion = "1";
    }else{


$arrCount = count($_SESSION['answer_array']);
    }
    if($arrCount > $numQuestions){
        unset($_SESSION['answer_array']);
        header("location: start-quiz.php");
        exit();
    }
    if($arrCount >= $numQuestions){
        echo 'finished|<p>There are no more questions. Please enter your username and submit</p>
                <form action="userAnswers.php" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="complete" value="true">
                <input type="text" name="username">
                <button class="btn btn-action" type="submit" value="finish">Submit</button>
                </form>';
        exit();
    }
    $singleSQL = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id='$question' LIMIT 1");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($singleSQL)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $thisQuestion = $row['question'];
            $type = $row['type'];
            $question_id = $row['question_id'];
            $q = '<h2>'.$thisQuestion.'</h2>';
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question' ORDER BY rand()");
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2)){
                $answer = $row2['answer'];
                $correct = $row2['correct'];
                $answers .= '<label style="cursor:pointer;"><input type="radio" name="rads" value="'.$correct.'">'.$answer.'</label> 
                <input type="hidden" id="qid" value="'.$id.'" name="qid"><br /><br />
                ';

            }
            $output = ''.$q.','.$answers.',<span id="btnSpan"><button onclick="post_answer()"class="btn btn-action">Submit</button></span>';
            echo $output;
           }
        }
```

I'm guessing rather than have a submit button that takes you to the next page, after clicking on a radio button, the vote should show and then the teacher can push the next question. That's were the main issue is.

Comment: If you want to use _push_ updates look into websockets. xmlhttprequest can only do pull. You can't push from a database, but you can push from any other event source (like a teacher :P)

Comment: @Halcyon thanks for the information. My main issue now is getting to see the votes after a user has clicked on an answer.